# Attempted XPath query not showing any results

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath

I'm currently working on a fantasy sports site, and I want to be able to pull basic stats from another site. (I don't have much experience with XML or pulling data from other sites).

I inspected the element to gain it's XPath:

[image: Getting XPath]

Which gave me: `//*[@id="cp1_ctl01_pnlPlayerStats"]/table[1]/tbody/tr[4]/td[18]`

I've looked into a couple methods of trying to pull the info and came up with this:

[image: Code 1]

But I just end up with empty elements in my table within my site:

[image]

Here's My Code:

```
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        @$doc->loadHTMLFile($P_RotoLink);

        $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

        $elements = $xpath->query('//*  [@id="cp1_ctl01_pnlPlayerStats"]/table[1]/tbody/tr[4]/td[18]');

        if (!is_null($elements)) {
            foreach ($elements as $element) {
                $nodes = $element->childNodes;
                foreach ($nodes as $node) {
                    echo $node->nodeValue. "\n";
                }
            }
        }
```

A few things I've tried have thrown me errors, and any time I finally get pass them or suppress them I get empty content. I've tried a bunch of different formats but none seem to give me the desired content.

Edit: Here's the source HTML, I want to grab the value within the td (13.0).

[image]

Edit 2: So this is what I'm trying now:

```
$html = file_get_contents($P_RotoLink);

$doc = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($html);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
$xpath = new DOMXpath( $doc);

foreach ($xpath->query('//*[@id="cp1_ctl01_pnlPlayerStats"]/table//tr[4]/td[18]') as $node) {
                                        $ppg = substr($node->textContent,0,3);
                                        echo $ppg;
                                    }
```

[image]

Comment: Show us the source HTML for the node having `id=cp1_ctl01_pnlPlayerStats` and what exactly you want to fetch from the node.

Comment: I want to capture and display the value '13.0'

Comment: The table in the last screenshot doesn't have `tbody` node. Try this: `//[@id="cp1_ctl01_pnlPlayerStats"]/table//tr[4]/td[18]`. You should paste the code into the question instead of making screenshots, as it is very difficult to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I did that for my little piece but didn't know if I should do it for the code from the other site. I did what you said, but now I get: Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression

Comment: Ah, indeed. Try this: `//*[@id="cp1_ctl01_pnlPlayerStats"]/table//tr[4]/td[18]`. That's why you should paste the code (including the source HTML for the node) into the question. I'd have posted this as an answer, if I had opportunity to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! It gives several more decimal places, but I can just manipulate the info now that I have it. Do you want to post that as the answer so I can select it or should I just answer my own?

Comment: `DOMXPath::query` returns a `DOMNodeList`, if the XPath expression is valid. Since the expression selects only one cell (`td[18]`), the length of the list will be either one (if found), or zero (if not found). So you should fetch the first node from the list (an instance of `DOMElement`) and fetch its `nodeValue`. I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the table in the screenshot doesn't have `tbody` node, but your XPath expression includes `tbody` which causes `DOMXPath::query` to return an empty list of nodes. I suggest ignoring `tbody` and fetching only rows with `//tr`.

**Example**

```
$html = <<<'HTML'
<div id="cp1_ctl01_pnlPlayerStats">
  <table>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>0.9</span>1.0<span>3.0</span></td><td>2.0</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
HTML;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);
$expr = '//*[@id="cp1_ctl01_pnlPlayerStats"]/table//tr[2]/td[1]/text()';
$td = $xp->query($expr);
if ($td->length) {
  var_dump($td[0]->nodeValue);
}
```

*Output*

```
string(3) "1.0"
```

The `text()` function selects all text node children of the context node.

Comment: Ok so I'm getting the data, but something else is appending and I can't seem to get rid of it even with a substr(). See my new edit.

Comment: It's like another decimal, but I have no idea where it's coming from and even my substr() doesn't get rid of it.

Comment: @EthanGuillotte, use `text()` XPath function. I've updated the answer. To strip leading and trailing spaces, use either `text()[normalize-space()]` expression, or `trim()` in PHP